# android monkeyrunner waitForConnection hang forever

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

My environment consist of Ubuntu 13.04, Optimus Q2 with ics.

when I run the following code, it prints 0 but never 1

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

# Imports the monkeyrunner modules used by this program
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
print "0"
# Connects to the current device, returning a MonkeyDevice object
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()

print "1"
```

do I have to change my Ubuntu to Windows, install smartphone driver, and then try again?

Comment: Start by getting your device displayed in `adb devices`

Comment: Do you get any output besides the "0"? Particularly error messages, stack trace, etc. What happens to script - does it time out, fail immediately, or is cancelled manually?

Comment: do you have 'adb' binary copied somewhere else other than android-sdk folder?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because you try to run multiple scripts one inside another. It's sync issue I presume.